# Since archive.ubuntu.com does not support HTTPS, is there any alternative server that does?

Tags: apt, configuration, encryption, official-repositories, https

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146108/how-to-use-https-with-apt-get#comment239421_146117) hadn't been asked separately, so here it is.

In particular, is there any *official* repository that provides and https alternative to the defaults http official repositories?

Answer (score 2):

`mirrors.kernel.org` is an official Ubuntu archive mirror, and supports https.

I have the following in my `sources.list`:

```
deb https://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu saucy main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src https://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu saucy main restricted universe multiverse
```

(Technically, `mirrors.kernel.org` is not on the official list, though `mirrors.us.kernel.org` and its siblings are.  However, `mirrors.us.kernel.org` supports https but returns a certificate for the host `mirrors.kernel.org` which `apt-get` rejects.  `mirrors.kernel.org` is clearly the same site, though it may not be your closest host.)

As pointed out, https is not necessary for authenticating the files downloaded, and is not very effective at hiding which files you download.  My interest is because at my site, http downloads are much slower than https for some reason, even from the same remote host.  I don't know why; maybe we have a transparent proxy that is slow or trying to scan for viruses or some such nonsense.